# $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a bounded open set such that $\mathbb{R}^{2} -U$ is not connected. Then $U$ is not contractible .

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a bounded open set such that $\mathbb{R}^{2} -U$ is not connected. Then I want to conclude that $U$ is not contractible (to a point).

> **My attempt**

We proceed by contradiction so we assume that $U$ is contractible to a point. Let $[x_i],...,[x_n],...$ be the connected components of $\mathbb{R}-U$ then

$$\mathbb{R^2}-U = \cup_j [x_j] $$

Therefore

$$U= \cap (\mathbb{R^2}-[x_j])$$

Then $\cap (\mathbb{R^2}-[x_j])$ is contractible to a point but this is not true because the complement of connected sets is not always connected.

The thing is that I am not using boundedness and the part that "**the complement of connected sets is not always connected**" I think is wrong so How can I conclude the result?

---

**Note:** I have been searching and in Spivak's book says as a hint of this same problem that I $p$ is in a bounded component of $\mathbb{R^2}-U$ then I have to conclude that there is a curve in $U$ such that "surrounds" $p$, but what does he mean by surrounds, and how something in the complement can be surrounded by something in $U$ if they are distinct sets?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The fact that in general the complement of connected sets is not *always* connected does not imply that in this case the intersection of the complements is not connected. In particular, in your example each complement, and the intersection $U$, are all connected. So your proof fails to apply to this case.

Comment: Ok so how can I fix it ?

Comment: If $p$ is in one of the bounded components of $\Bbb R^2 - U$, then $U$ completely encircles $p$ - otherwise the component of $p$ is unbounded. Actually proving the existance of the closed curve is harder, though. But once you have it, it cannot be contracted to a point without passing through $p$. Since a contraction of $U$ would provide a contraction of the curve that avoids $p$, no contraction of $U$ is possible.

Comment: So can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: Elaborate about what? I can't give you a proof of the existance ot the closed curve, as I don't have the time. What are you not understanding?

Comment: Sorry I mean can you explain more why something in the complement can be enclose by something in the set ?

Comment: Pull out that example you deleted from your original post. There are three holes in it. $p$ is in one of the holes. You can easily draw closed curves in $U$ that encircle that hole (just take a curve parallel to the boundary but slightly larger). Curves like that is what Spivak is referring to. But proving that the curve exists in general can be tricky, as $U$ may have infinitely many holes.

Comment: Ok right, now once you have p in one of the holes can you explain why you cannot contract U ? Thanks in advance and sorry but I want to make sure I understand it because it is not obvious for me :)

Comment: A contraction of $U$ to a point provides a contraction of that curve around $p$ to a point without it passing through $p$ (since $p$ is not a part of $U$). But now we have a curve in $\Bbb R^2$ that encircles $p$ contracted to a point without the contraction passing through $p$. This is not possible. (You should have already seen the proof of that in your book.)

Comment: Ok :) just a second to get it

Comment: I imagined the picture, you have $p$ inside one of holes of $U$ but since that thing is contracting to something that is not in $U$ is a contradiction right ?

Comment: Not quite. If $U$ is contractible, then it, and that curve inside it, contracts to a point in $U$. But the entire contraction has to be inside $U$, so the curve cannot pass through $p$ during the contraction. But as $U$ is part of $\Bbb R^2$ we can consider the contraction of the curve in $\Bbb R^2$. The curve encircles $p$ but somehow contracts to a point without passing through $p$. This should have already been proven impossible in your book.

Comment: Right :) get it, now just a single question why is this not true in $R^3$ ? Is because here we know that contractible is the same as simply connected but what about in $R^3$ thanks in advance :)

Comment: Who says it isn't true in $\Bbb R^3$? The question you asked is not about being simply-connected. I believe (I can't say absolutely without more study) that for any locally compact locally path-connected contractible Hausdorff space $X$, if $U$ is an open set with compact closure and $X - U$ is not connected, then $U$ is not contractible. You might even be able to drop some of those conditions.

Comment: Right, but what about the assertion that contractible is the same as simply connected :)

Comment: Simply connected = path connected + every closed curve is homotopic to a point. In 2 dimensions, even a single point missing from the interior of the curve prevents it from contracting. But in three dimensions, it can just slip around any such compact hole. Think of the volume between two spheres. The space is homotopic to a sphere and so is not contractible, but any closed curve in it is contractible. So it is simply connected. It is the second fundamental group that is non-trivial, not the first.

Comment: I'm back @PaulSinclair but how is the sphere in three dimensions not contractible? Can you clarify your comment? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How would you contract a sphere to a point (remember the contraction is inside the space being contracted - you cannot contract the sphere to its center)? That is like pulling a closed cover off a ball - no matter how you pull on it, it still wraps around the ball. You have to have a hole in it to get the ball out. Any contractible space has all of its fundamental groups being trivial (the inverse is not true, there are non-contractible spaces with trivial fundamental groups) But the 2nd fundamental group of the sphere is not trivial.

Comment: Oh sorry but I recalled that the sphere from large dimensions have trivial fundamental group :) so is it wrong ?

Comment: Trivial FIRST fundamental group. $S^2$ has a non-trivial SECOND fundamental group. More generally $S^n$ will have a non-trivial $n$-th fundamental group. However all fundamental groups other than the $n$-th will be trivial.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what are the nth fundamental groups :)

Comment: Look them up. They are too much to explain here.

Comment: Ok but then the conclusion is that this holds for the Euclidean space of dimension 3 right ?

Comment: If by "this" you mean the original question, then I believe it holds for all $\Bbb R^n$, and a great many other spaces as well.

Comment: Well yes both conditions the question and the iff condition I have mentioned :)